# Commit and rollback statement (in a child stored procedure) affect main stored procedure in Postregsql?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 stored procedures in Postgresql: `sp_main`, `sp_child`.

`sp_main` calls `sp_child` in the procedure. The problem is that whenever `sp_child` input1 = -1 then it rollbacks `sp_main` first insert statement.

How can I use `savepoint` statement for this situation?

Question summary:

```
call1() --> call2()  (call2 will have commit/rollback but will not affect call1)
```

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_main(INOUT main_result integer)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin 
declare resultc integer
resultc=0;
---
---first insert
insert into table1
values(-1,'a'); --input1=-1
---
call sp_child(1,resultc); --call child sp. 
main_result=resultc;
---
---last insert
insert into table2
values(-7,'a');    
commit;
END ;
$$
;




CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_child(input1 integer DEFAULT 0,INOUT v_result integer DEFAULT 5)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin 
v_result=1;
---
---query_child
insert into table2
values(-10,'a');
---
    if input1=-1 then
            Rollback;
    end if;
END ;
$$
;



call sp_main(1);
```

Comment: what is the version of the postgresql your are using ?

Comment: Version 13 @mshabou

Comment: take a look at pg_background extension: https://dpavlin.wordpress.com/2017/05/09/david-rader-autonomous-transactions-using-pg_background/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A savepoint won't help you (in PL/pgSQL, that in implemented by a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block). A savepoint starts a subtransaction, but if you `ROLLBACK`, the whole transaction including all of its subtransactions will be aborted.

There is no way to keep a transaction open in `sp_main` if `sp_child` issues a `ROLLBACK`.

You will have to redesign your transaction handling. The way it is right now doesn't make sense anyway: Any `INSERT` that `sp_child` performs is rolled back.